# Find minimal polynomial of a difficult transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

we are asked to find the minimal polynomial of the transformation:

$T: M_n(\mathbb C)\to M_n(\mathbb C)$

$T(A)=CA$ when $C$ is a diagonal matrix with the values $c_1,c_2,c_3,...,c_n$ on the diagonal and $0$ everywhere else.

What I did:

I found the matrix of the transformation with respect to the standard base.

If I am not mistaken, it is a diagonal matrix with values $c_1,c_2,c_3,...c_n$ where every one of them is in the diagonal $n$ times.

So the characteristic polynomial is: $(t-c_1)^n(t-c_2)^n...(t-c_n)^n$

How do I find the minimal polynomial from here?

Obviously the minimal polynomial should be: $(t-c_1)^{\alpha_1}(t-c_2)^{\alpha_2}...(t-c_n)^{\alpha_n}$ but how do i find $\alpha_i$ for all $i$?

Comment: You have done most of the work.  Try $(t-c_1)\cdots(t-c_n)$ and work your way up from there.

Comment: How will I know? I can't say for sure if $(A-c_1I)...(A-c_nI)=0$ or maybe $(A-c_1I)^2...(A-c_n)=0$ so on and so forth...@StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: You need to consider $(T(A) - c_1 I)\cdots(T(A) - c_n I))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Note that for every polynomial $p(X)$ we have $p(T)(A)=p(C)A$. No basis needed.

**Remark** If you focus on the [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29#Formal_definition) of the minimal polynomial, you will see that this observation shows, in general, that the minimal polynomial of the left-multiplication $T:A\longmapsto CA$ is the same as the minimal polynomial of the matrix $C$, as they have the same annihilating ideals ($I_T=I_C$). For every matrix $C$. So it boils down to determining the latter, which is easy here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you mean that the characteristic polynomial is not basis dependant, I know that, but how does it help me find the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @OriaGruber Well, $p(T)=0$ if and only if $p(C)=0$. And the minimal polynomial is the monic generator of the annihilating ideal of $T$.

Comment: In your formula, T and C are matrices of the same transformation but in a different basis?

Comment: By $P(T)(A)$ he means the operator $P(T)$ applied to A.  By $p(C)A$ he means the matrix $P(C)$ times the matrix $A$.

Comment: I still don't understand how any of this is related to the minimal polynomial

Comment: It should help you to work out $(T(A) - c_1 I)\cdots(T(A) - c_n I))$.

Comment: its the zero matrix!! :D

Comment: @OriaGruber From your comments, I understand it could be helpful for you to read the formal definition of the minimal polynomial. In a case like that, it makes the exercise more straightforward than the eigenvalue-by-eigenvalue-approach you are using. See my edit.